# Question on Axioms of probability

Tags: probability

Let $\mathbf{A_1,A_2, . . . , A_n}$ be events. Let $\mathbf{B_k}$ be the event that at least k of the $\mathbf{A_i}$ occur, and $\mathbf{C_k}$ be the event that exactly k of the $\mathbf{A_i}$ occur, for $\mathbf{0 \leq k \leq n}$. Find a simple expression for P($\mathbf{B_k}$) in terms of P($\mathbf{C_k}$) and P($\mathbf{C_{k+1}}$)

I tried getting an expression but did not succeed. Is this a valid relation? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the count of events of the sequence $\{A_i\}_{i\in\{1..n\}}$ that occur.

Then for $B_k\equiv\{X\leq k\}$, $C_k\equiv\{X=k\}$ we have

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B_k) ~=~& \mathsf P\{X\leq k\} \\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P\{X\leq k+1\}-\mathsf P\{X=k+1\}\\[1ex] =~&\mathsf P(B_{k+1})-\mathsf P(C_{k+1})\\[2ex]\mathsf P(B_k) ~=~& \mathsf P\{X\leq k\} \\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P\{X=k\}+\mathsf P\{X\leq k-1\}\\[1ex] =~&\mathsf P(C_{k})+\mathsf P(B_{k-1})\\[2ex]2\mathsf P(B_k)~=~& \mathsf P(C_k)-\mathsf P(C_{k+1})+\mathsf P(B_{k+1})+\mathsf P(B_{k-1})\end{align}$$

So, no, you cannot find a simple expression for $\mathsf P(B_k)$ in terms of $\mathsf P(C_k)$ and $\mathsf P(C_{k+1})$ unless you include other terms.

Comment: Indeed that is what I was thinking. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @GrahamKemp In your answer, shouldn't $B_{k}=\{X\geq k\}$?